# How can I merge 2 files line by line with same record in awk/shell?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, awk

I am new in awk and shell, wondering how can I merge 2 files with the line that have the same record using shell/awk? file1 and file2 may have different order for the Name. I only want to merge the lines that has the same record. please help.

```
file1.txt
Mary 68 
Tom 50 
Jason 45
Lu 66

file2.txt
Jason 37
Tom 26
Mary 74
Tina 80

mergefile.txt
Marry 68 74
Tom 50 26
Jason 45 37
```

I have a try of awk, but it takes some times to running the script. Wondering if there could be a more faster and simple implement.

```
cat file1.txt | while read line
do
    score1=$( echo $line | awk '{print $2}');
    name1=$( echo $line | awk '{print $1}');

    cat file2.txt | while read l
    do
        score2=$( echo $l | awk '{print $2}');
        name2=$( echo $l | awk '{print $1}');
        if [[ $name1 == $name2 ]]
        then
            echo "$name1 $score1 $score2" >> mergefile
            break
        fi
    done
done
```

Comment: You have some beginner mistakes in your script. Copy/paste it into https://www.shellcheck.net/ to see s list of several of them and then also read https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice, https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes, http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html, and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/133219 for more on those and other issues. Finally - never name a variable `l` as it looks far too much like the number `1` and so obfuscates your code.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use awk:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1] = $2; next} $1 in a {print $1, $2, a[$1]}' file2.txt file1.txt 
Mary 68 74
Tom 50 26
Jason 45 37
```

No sorting is required and the output will be in the order of the second file given.

Explanation:

- `NR==FNR` is the canonical way to select records from the first named file
- `{a[$1] = $2; next}` populate an array with keys from the first field and values from the second
- `$1 in a` if the first field was already seen in the first file; then
- `{print $1, $2, a[$1]}` print the key and value from the second file and the value from the first

Comment: can you explain the awk command, thanks

Comment: @Tiger please see edit

Answer (score 5):

This sound like a job for [`join`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/join.html), the relational database operator

```
join <(sort file1.txt) <(sort file2.txt)
```

Tests

```
$ cat file1.txt
Mary 68
Tom 50
Jason 45
Lu 66

$ cat file2.txt
Jason 37
Tom 26
Mary 74
Tina 80

$ join <(sort file1.txt) <(sort file2.txt)
Jason 45 37
Mary 68 74
Tom 50 26
```

`join` is standard tool specified in POSIX.

The `join` man page states:

> ```
> The files file1 and file2 shall be ordered in the collating sequence of sort -b on the 
> fields on which they shall be joined, by default the first in each line. All selected 
> output shall be written in the same collating sequence.
> ```

Comment: if I want to combine 2 files together, can "join" do the work? also combine the name and scores that only appears in one file?

Comment: @Tiger What do you mean by "combine 2 files together". See the `join` link in my answer to understand what its purpose.